# Optimizing functions in Linear Programming

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

I would like to know if it makes sense to formulate a LP problem in the following way:

1. Define constant coefficients of the objective function ($C_i = 1$ for all $i$)

max $x1 + x2 + ... xN$

2. and then define the variables as functions of theirselves in the constraints:

max $x1 + x2 + ... xN$

$s.t$

$x1 = f_1(x1)$
$x2 = f_2(x2)$
...
$xN = f_N(xN)$

In this case, all the functions $f_i(x)$ for $i=1...N$ are known.

Thank you very much :)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

You can, but whether it makes sense is up for debate.

If you have the constraint $x_i = f(x_i)$ in a linear program, that means $f$ is affine, hence the constraints are $x_i = a + bx_i$ with solution $x_i = a/(1-b)$ meaning there is nothing to optimize.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now, would it be different (and feasible) to formulate it like:   max $u1 + u2 + .... + uN$ s.t $u1 = f(x1)$; $u2 = f(x2)$ .... $uN = f(xN)$. Still the variables that  I want fo find values for are $x_i$. Thank you!

Comment: Sure you can, but without context (i.e. other constraints in the model) it is not clear why one would want to do it as you only increase the number of variables and constraints without any benefit.

Comment: Okay! The context is: I know $N$ functions $f_i(x)$ for $i=1...N$ that belong to $N$ products of a store. $f_i(x)$ returns the amount of units sold for product $i$ once I invest the amount $x$ to the product $i$. The input to the model is actually the total amount $B$ and the problem is: How do I distribute $B$ over all products to maximize the sum of the total units? So another constraint that I had not defined is that the sum of all $x_i$ is equal to $B$. I hope it is more clear now. Thank you!

Comment: So I guess you have $x\geq 0, \sum x_i = B$. It is not clear why you would want to move the terms from the objective function to the constraints, thereby increasing the number of variables and constraints at no benefit at all as I can see. The new objective in the LP will look exactly the same with same structure/sparsity. And unless I am missing something, the solution is to allocate $B$ to the $x_i$ with largest coefficients, and set all other to $0$

Comment: I understand your comments! A fix in your intuition of the problem: As $f_i(x)$ are all logarithmic  functions (I had not told that to you before), allocating $B$ to only one $x_i$ will not be optimal as I would rather prefer exploiting the beginning of the logarithmic curves for all products in some way. Although allocating $B$ to only one $x_i$ is a feasible solution, it will definately not be optimal. Note: I edited the main question to reflect that $f(x)$ is not the same for all variables, but I have $f_i(x)$ for variable $x_i$ instead.

Comment: Logarithms are not affine, so why are you talking about linear programming? If you want to maximize $\sum c_i \log(a_ix_i+b_i)$ (with non-negative $c_i$)  you have a convex nonlinear program. It has to be solved with a nonlinear programming solver (or an exponential cone solver), and the logarithmic terms should definitely not be moved to equality constraints as that renders the problem non-convex. It is an easy nonlinear program

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments. You were very helpful. By the way, do you have any recommendation for such solvers? Python or R is preferred in this case. Thank you!

Comment: I am not familiar with Python or R, but any nonlinear optimization framework there should work. In MATLAB it is trivial https://yalmip.github.io/tutorial/generalconvexprogramming/.

Comment: Great. Another question: if instead of $sum(c_i * log(a_i*x_i + b_i))$ I had $sum( exp( c_i * log(a_i*x_i + b_i)  + C))$ would the problem still be convex?($C$ being a constant) In the case it would not be convex, exponential cone solvers would not work anymore right? So the only choice would be a general nonlinear nonconvex solver? Thank you very much

Comment: Depends on $c$. You have $\sum (a_ix_i + b_i)^{c_i}$ which is concave for $0<c_i < 1$ thus rendering the problem convex.

Comment: Actually: $c_i = 0.2$ for all $i$

Comment: So convex problem then, and also second-order cone representable, power cone representable and in exp/log form probably exponential-cone representable too. In YALMIP you would simply write cpower(A*x + b,0.2)